# Android: Starting a new activity from TabHost disables onClick

Tags: android, onclick, android-tabhost

I have a TabActivity with 4 tabs. When clicking on a button within one of the tabs and starting a new Activity (a new Activity not within the TabHost), the new Activity does not register OnClick(). The new Activity can't even show a Toast wich makes me think the TabHost is somehow blocking the ui?

When putting the Activity as one of the Tabs the OnClick works just fine.
Any ideas what the reason for this is?

I've included 3 classes:

1) The TabActivity

2) The Activity in a tab that starts:

3) The new Activity that cannot register OnClick()

---

1) TabActivity:

```
public class OverView extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);

        /** TabHost will have Tabs */
        TabHost tabHost     = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        /** TabSpec used to create a new tab.
         * By using TabSpec only we can able to setContent to the tab.
         * By using TabSpec setIndicator() we can set name to tab. */

        /** tid1 is firstTabSpec Id. Its used to access outside. */
        TabSpec Search      = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec AllArtists  = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec Favorites   = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec About       = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");

        /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        Search.     setIndicator("Search");
        AllArtists. setIndicator("AllArtists");
        Favorites.  setIndicator("Favorites");
        About.      setIndicator("About");

        /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
        Search.setContent       (new Intent(this, Search.class));
        AllArtists.setContent   (new Intent(this, AllArtists.class));
        Favorites.setContent    (new Intent(this, Favorites.class));
        About.setContent        (new Intent(this, About.class));

        /** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(Search);
        tabHost.addTab(AllArtists);
        tabHost.addTab(Favorites);
        tabHost.addTab(About);
    }
}
```

2) AllArtists (The Activity within the tab. Clicking a list item starts a new Activity):

```
public class AllArtists extends Activity {

    // Debug
    private final String    TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();  

    // XML
    EditText                searchBox;
    ListView                listView;

    // Adapter
    ListAdapter             listAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allartists);

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, null);

        // XML
        listView    = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.allartists_listview);
        searchBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.allartists_searchbox);

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String memberID = (String)listAdapter.getID(position).toString();

                if (!memberID.equals("HEADER")){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Jumping to Artists.class");
                    Intent intentArtist = new Intent (AllArtists.this, Artist.class);
                    intentArtist.putExtra("ID", memberID);
                    startActivity(intentArtist);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

3) Artist (The new Activity started. This class does not register OnClick):

```
public class Artist extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

// Debug
private final String    TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();  

// XML
Button          favorite_btn;

LinearLayout    tel;
LinearLayout    mob;
LinearLayout    email;
LinearLayout    www1;
LinearLayout    www2;
LinearLayout    add;

TextView        name_tv;
TextView        tel_tv;
TextView        mob_tv;
TextView        email_tv;
TextView        www_tv1;
TextView        www_tv2;

// Strings
String memberID;
String sirName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_artist);

    Toast.makeText(this, "OK, your in Activity_Artist..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


    // XML
    favorite_btn    = (Button)findViewById(R.id.artist_ib_favorite);

    tel             = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.artist_tel_container);
    mob             = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.artist_mob_container);
    email           = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.artist_email_container);
    www1            = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.artist_www_container1);
    www2            = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.artist_www_container2);
    add             = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.artist_add_container);

    name_tv         = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist_tv_name);
    tel_tv          = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist_tel_dynamic);
    mob_tv          = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist_mob_dynamic);
    email_tv        = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist_email_dynamic);
    www_tv1         = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist_www_dynamic1);
    www_tv2         = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist_www_dynamic2);

    // OnClickListeners
    favorite_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    tel.setOnClickListener(this);
    mob.setOnClickListener(this);
    email.setOnClickListener(this);
    www1.setOnClickListener(this);
    www2.setOnClickListener(this);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Code here to get memberID for fillContent()
}

private void fillContent(String memberID) throws JSONException {
// Code here to fill the TextViews etc with content from the DataBase.
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.artist_ib_favorite:
        Toast.makeText(this, "onClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.d(TAG, "Neo is attempting to insert member into favorites");

        MyDB db = new MyDB(this);
        db.insertFavorite(memberID, sirName);

        break;

    case R.id.artist_tel_container:
        break;

    case R.id.artist_mob_container:
        Log.d(TAG, "OMG CLICKED THE MOBILE!");
        break;

    case R.id.artist_email_container:
        break;

    case R.id.artist_www_container1:
        break;

    case R.id.artist_add_container:
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. In the layout there was an (empty) GridView at the bottom of the layout set to android:layout_height="fill_parent" wich stole the touchevent.

The weird part about this is that when putting the exact same activity with the exact same XML inside a tab, the onClick() worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Toast you need to call show.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "OK, your in Activity_Artist..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For the click Operation on anything apart from Button you need to define

```
android:clickable="true"
```

in the layout.

Comment: Hhaha not the first time I've forgotten to add .show(). I have actually never used android:clickable="true" and I've never had any problems with things being clickable. Isn't the default set to true?

Comment: Apart from that I do not see any reason why the click event is not propogated given this is not part of the TabHost Activity, the onClick should be consumed in this activity itself.